# Webaudio timing performance

Tags: web-audio-api, tonejs

The file below uses ToneJS to play a steam of steady 8th notes. According to the log of the timing, those 8th notes are precisely 0.25 seconds apart.

However, they don't *sound* even. The time intervals between the notes are distinctly irregular.

Why is it so? Is there anything that can be done about it? Or is this a performance limitation of Javascript/webaudio-api? I have tested it in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari, all to the same result.

Thanks for any information or suggestions about this!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Tone Timing Tester</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tone/14.8.32/Tone.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<button onclick="start()">Start</button>
<button onclick="stop()">Stop</button>
<form>
    <input id="bpm" type="number" value="120">
    <button type="button" onclick="submitBPM()">Enter BPM</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    
    var synth = new Tone.Synth().toDestination()

    Tone.Transport.scheduleRepeat(function(time){
        console.log('time', time);
        synth.triggerAttackRelease('C4', '8n')
    }, "8n");

    async function start() {
        await Tone.start()
        Tone.Transport.start();
    }

    function stop() {
        Tone.Transport.stop();
    }

    function submitBPM() {
        var bpm = document.getElementById('bpm').value;
        Tone.Transport.bpm.value = bpm;
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a scheduled `triggerAttackRelease`, you should pass the `time` value as the third argument.

```
Tone.Transport.scheduleRepeat(function(time){
    console.log('time', time);
    synth.triggerAttackRelease('C4', '8n', time);
}, "8n");
```

Here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/joeweiss/pen/RwZjMdY?editors=0010) that contains the working code.